# Return HttpResponseMessage before action without disposing Service

Tags: c#, async-await

I am new to async programming and do not 100% understand the implementations.
Hence I couldn't find a solution for my problem which I think is quite simple.

I need to return an HttpResponseMessage before I run some expensive tasks.
The problem is, if I run the program as shown in the code below, the `return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);`
 will be executed after the `GetAsyncCompanySettingsByGroup`.

So how can I first return the HttpResponseMessage and then execute the async task?

```
public class EventController : ApiController
{
    public readonly  ICompanyApiSettingsService CompApiService;
    public EventController(ICompanyApiSettingsService _CompApiService)
    {
        CompApiService = _CompApiService;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]JObject tlAction, int group)
    {
        var TlAction = tlAction.ToObject<TeamLeaderAction>();
        TlAction.api_group = group;

        //return BadRequest if values are missing
       if(group == null ||  string.IsNullOrEmpty(TlAction.object_type) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(TlAction.event_type))
         return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);


           await Task.Run(() => CompApiService.GetAsyncCompanySettingsByGroup(TlAction.api_group));

            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);


    }
  }
```

Initialy I didn't use a Async Post, and the await.
that worked but then my CompApiService was already disposed.

Comment: await allow the statements to run in sequence without blocking the thread. You could remove the await but will have its own side effects. You would need to remove the task and async from the method definition

Comment: If I remove the task and async method, I have problems with my Service. because it wil be desposed after the return.

Comment: You know those side effects I mentioned before. yep

Comment: This is called fire and forget. There are multiple solutions for this might want to check out [this](https://www.hangfire.io/). The problem with disposition is that you are registering in Scoped context and scoped only exist while the http context exists.